# chrome, make interface larger?

Tags: google-chrome

How do I make everything larger in this area?

I'm using: 31,5" - 2560 * 1440 - 125%

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNgeC.png

Answer (score 0):

solution: Start the browser with the /force-device-scale-factor=1 flag, replacing 1 with whatever you want your scale to be.